# When I use the HDFS, can I directly config the maximum space one datanode can use?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I use the HDFS, I can config the maximum used space by setting the value of dfs.datanode.du.reserved in hdfs-site.xml, but can I config it in the opposite way, directly set the max space to be used such as 50G, 100G, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set max size to be 50g or 100g but why would you do that because that will increase your upgrade time.

Comment: Thanks！ So could you tell me how to set the max size to be 50g, and by the way, does the "upgrade time" you said mean to the rolling upgrade?